# Getting a "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null"

Tags: javascript

I'm practicing my vanilla JS and trying to create dynamic elements. I came across some interesting behavior. I am simply creating a button, click it and then have it render onto the DOM. But then I want to create another event that mouses over the h1 elements and changes the color, however I get a "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null". Why is this showing up as null if there is a h1 on the DOM and why does it now say cannot read property "addEventListener" of null?

```
HTML
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Creating Dynamic Elements</title>
</head>
<body>
  
</body>
</html>
```

```
JavaScript

// const h1 = document.querySelectorAll('h1');  
const button = document.createElement('button');
button.textContent = "Click me";
document.querySelector('body').appendChild(button);

button.addEventListener('click', function() {
  const h1 = document.createElement('h1');
  h1.textContent = 'Hello World!';
  document.querySelector('body').appendChild(h1);
});

document.querySelector('h1').addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
  alert("It works!");
});
```

Comment: There is no `h1` at the time you're trying to select it and add an event listener.

Comment: It runs for me, without any error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add your h1 event listener inside the function since there's no h1 on load.

```js
const button = document.createElement('button');
button.textContent = "Click me";
document.querySelector('body').appendChild(button);

button.addEventListener('click', function() {
  const h1 = document.createElement('h1');
  h1.textContent = 'Hello World!';
  document.querySelector('body').appendChild(h1);

  h1.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
    alert("It works!");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It wont work because your DOM don't have any "h1" elements when the addEventListner line is executed
you can instead move it inside the button Event Listener Function

Also `document.querySelect()` selects only the first element with the selector
if you want it to work with each h1 element you add, you should use the variable that refers to the element you dynamicly created in your code

```
const button = document.createElement('button');
button.textContent = "Click me";
document.querySelector('body').appendChild(button);

button.addEventListener('click', function() {
  const h1 = document.createElement('h1');
  h1.textContent = 'Hello World!';
  document.querySelector('body').appendChild(h1);
  /* This will only select the first h1 element in the whole document
  document.querySelector('h1').addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
    alert("It works!");
  });
  */
  //This will add the event listener to every h1 element you create
  h1.addEventListner('mouseover', function() {
    alert("It works!");
  });
});
```